# Making hidden menu for mobile view

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

I have made a site navigation for onepage style layout and I was hoping that someone could help me with mobile layout of navigation.

Navigation looks fine in bigger screens, but i would like to hide all menu items for mobile view unless you click it. After clicking (also in touchscreen) all the menu items would show.

I really would appreciate your help!

I have this in my fluid.css

```
#nav {
background-color:#fff;
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
min-height:40px;
display: block;}

#nav ul {
    padding-top:8px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    padding: 6px 26px 8px 26px;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav ul li:first-child {
border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

#nav a {
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
color: #515151;
font-weight: 300;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav a:visited {
color: #515151;
}

#nav a:hover {
color: #000;
}
```

/*Inherits style from mobile layout*/

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {}
```

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {}
```

I also use sticky navigation from http://labs.anthonygarand.com/sticky
and it also needs latest

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Hide the Nav(Desktop) from the mobile version, and create another with Dropdown, which is only visible in Mobiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 480 ){
        $("#nav").sticky({topSpacing:0}); //do stuff for mobile screens here
    }
    else{
        $("#nav").attr('style', '');
    }
  });
```